# DataRetrievalFailureException when saving aggregate root using Azure SQL Server

Tags: spring-data-jdbc

Problem Description -

- Saving aggregate roots without embedded entities works fine
- The issue arises when saving an aggregate root which aggregates another entity (one-to-one containment relationship)
- Spring Data JDBC seems to behave correctly as I see the correct prepared statements (insert of root entity, get generated keys, and then insert of the aggregated entity)
- It seems to me the issue arises within the GenerateKeyHold class which is receiving a "keyList" with one entry "[{GENERATED_KEYS=null}]"
- The code tests against an empty list but not against a null GENERATED_KEYS
- The database driver correctly inserts the row but then the code tries to retrieve a generated id but it is null and hence the cast exception
- I am including sample code (entity, script-creation) and the stack trace
- Note that I didn't observe this issue when using the in-memory H2 database
- I am using spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE which is pulling spring-data-jdbc:jar:1.0.5.RELEASE

I would really appreciate if you could help me figure out the cause of such an issue; I did lot of research but nobody is reporting such a problem (except for an Oracle DB because of ROWID to Number casting)

Entities

```
    // EntityA owns an instance of EntityB
    @Data
    static class EntityA {
        @Id Long id;

        String field1;
        EntityB entityB;
    }

    @Data
    static class EntityB {
        String field2;
    }
```

SQL Server create-script

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS entity_a;
    GO;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS entity_b;
    GO;

    CREATE TABLE entity_a ( 
      id BIGINT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
      field1 VARCHAR(100)
    );

    GO;
    CREATE TABLE entity_b ( 
      entity_a BIGINT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
      field2 VARCHAR(100)
    );
    GO;
```

Exception

```
    2019-03-20 17:45:35,482 DEBUG o.s.j.c.JdbcTemplate [update:891] [main] - Executing SQL update and returning generated keys
    2019-03-20 17:45:35,486 DEBUG o.s.j.c.JdbcTemplate [execute:609] [main] - Executing prepared SQL statement [INSERT INTO entity_a (field1) VALUES (?)]
    2019-03-20 17:45:35,590 DEBUG o.s.j.c.JdbcTemplate [update:891] [main] - Executing SQL update and returning generated keys
    2019-03-20 17:45:35,595 DEBUG o.s.j.c.JdbcTemplate [execute:609] [main] - Executing prepared SQL statement [INSERT INTO entity_b (field2, entity_a) VALUES (?, ?)]
    2019-03-20 17:45:35,621 ERROR c.m.s.c.l.LogUtil [error:74] [main] - org.springframework.data.relational.core.conversion.DbActionExecutionException: Failed to execute DbAction.Insert(entity=EntityB [field2=data2], propertyPath=EntityB, dependingOn=DbAction.InsertRoot(entity=EntityA [id=6, field1=data1, entityB=EntityB [field2=data2]], generatedId=6), additionalValues={}, generatedId=null)
    at org.springframework.data.relational.core.conversion.DbAction.executeWith(DbAction.java:57)
    at org.springframework.data.relational.core.conversion.AggregateChange.lambda$executeWith$0(AggregateChange.java:73)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    at org.springframework.data.relational.core.conversion.AggregateChange.executeWith(AggregateChange.java:71)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.JdbcAggregateTemplate.save(JdbcAggregateTemplate.java:104)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.support.SimpleJdbcRepository.save(SimpleJdbcRepository.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:359)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:644)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:608)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.mapr.sky.subscriptions.repository.db.tests.persistence.basic.$Proxy72.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.mapr.sky.subscriptions.repository.db.tests.persistence.basic.BasicRepoTest.crudTest(BasicRepoTest.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) 
    .
    .
    Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataRetrievalFailureException: The generated key is not of a supported numeric type. Unable to cast [null] to [java.lang.Number]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.GeneratedKeyHolder.getKey(GeneratedKeyHolder.java:79)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.DefaultDataAccessStrategy.getIdFromHolder(DefaultDataAccessStrategy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.DefaultDataAccessStrategy.insert(DefaultDataAccessStrategy.java:111)
    at org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.DefaultJdbcInterpreter.interpret(DefaultJdbcInterpreter.java:61)
    at org.springframework.data.relational.core.conversion.DbAction$Insert.doExecuteWith(DbAction.java:86)
    at org.springframework.data.relational.core.conversion.DbAction.executeWith(DbAction.java:55)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug/missing feature in Spring Data JDBC.
Support for MS SqlServer isn't really there yet.

Could you create an issue for this? 
And since you seem already digging a little into the code, maybe you might even want to submit a PR?

Comment: Yes, I can try and submit a PR fix. Note that the Spring Data JDBC github page (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc) indicates that mssql is already amongst the databases the test-suite is using.

Comment: There is infrastructure in place for running integration tests against it, but many of the tests are actually ignored because they demonstrate issues like the one you found. Of course, I see how that is misleading.

Comment: Noticed the reported issue has been fixed in the current  spring-data-jdbc master branch; the MS SQL Server testsuite is also now operational. Thanks to @JensSchauder for his help!

Comment: There are still thinks that don't work with MS-SqlServer (updates, if I remember correctly). Check for ignored test in the test suite.